Audio stuttering on Ubuntu 22.04 laptop when HDMI monitor is attached
I am experiencing audio stuttering/glitches when I have an HDMI monitor connected (the monitor has speakers but I do not use them, I use headphones).
I followed advice at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/736690/111851 and disabled the NVIDIA HDMI audio PCI device using udev rules and the audio glitches reduced greatly, but after about 10 minutes of listening the audio glitches appear again when I have the monitor plugged in. The moment I unplug the HDMI monitor the audio glitches go away.
The glitches appear regardless of whether I listen to audio through my USB DAC adapter or the 3.5mm jack on the laptop itself.
Summary of my system at the moment (note NVIDIA HDMI audio has been force removed via udev rules):
System:
  Host: jwa-rog2023 Kernel: 6.8.0-45-generic x86_64 bits: 64
    Desktop: GNOME 42.9 Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: ASUSTeK product: ROG Strix G614JU_G614JU v: 1.0
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: ASUSTeK model: G614JU v: 1.0 serial: <superuser required>
    UEFI: American Megatrends LLC. v: G614JU.329 date: 06/03/2024
CPU:
  Info: 24-core (8-mt/16-st) model: 13th Gen Intel Core i9-13980HX bits: 64
    type: MST AMCP cache: L2: 32 MiB
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel driver: i915 v: kernel
  Device-2: NVIDIA driver: nvidia v: 550.107.02
  Device-3: Sonix USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam type: USB driver: uvcvideo
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.4 driver: X:
    loaded: modesetting,nvidia unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa gpu: i915,nvidia
    resolution: 2560x1440~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel Graphics (RPL-S)
    v: 4.6 Mesa 23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel driver: snd_hda_intel
  Device-2: Cambridge Audio DacMagicXS 2.0 type: USB driver: snd-usb-audio
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k6.8.0-45-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes

